# Github Actions: How to handle Github Secrets and use them in Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-secret

I am a little confused on how to securely handle secrets and variables in my CI/CD workflow.

Setup:
I deploy my express app to my VPS where I run it in a docker container and I need the variables to be available in that container.

Currently I am writing them into a .env file and setting that file as the env_file in docker-compose.yml, but it's probably not a very secure way of doing it, since then there would be a .env file on the server with plain text secrets... is there a better way (best pratice)?

Also the .env file wont be created like this. I had to manually create it on the server, wouldn't `echo` create the file if its not already there?

```
  - name: Execute remote deployment script
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
    with:
      HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
      KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
      script: |

        # Change directory to the app folder
        cd /usr/src/app/

        # install dependencies
        npm ci --omit=dev

        # Stop and remove running containers
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down

        # Set environment variables stored in Github secrets
        echo "VITE_API_URL=${{ secrets.VITE_API_URL }}" > .env
        echo "DATABASE_URL=${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}" >> .env
        echo "SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}" >> .env
        echo "REFRESH_SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY }}" >> .env

        # start container and detach
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```